# jquery/javascript: looping an animation function with different ID tags one after each other?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have a function that I want to loop around using a different ID tag each time. This function is called when the navigation link is clicked. So far I have this and I would like to change txt1 to txt2 then txt 3 and up to txt5 thus playing each animation one after each other. Thanks!

```
function animetxt(){
$o=$("#txt1");
$o.html($o.text().replace(/([\S])/g,'<span>$1</span>'));
$o.css('display','inline-block');
$('span',$o).stop().css({position:'relative',
                         display:'inline-block',
                         opacity:0,
                         fontSize:84,
                         top:function(i){return Math.floor(Math.random()*500)*((i%2)?1:-1);},
                         left:function(i){return Math.floor(Math.random()*500)*((i%2)?1:-1);}
                        }).animate({opacity:1,fontSize:20,top:0,left:0},1000);}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create an array with all the Ids and iterate over them using `$.each`:

```
$.each(['txt1', 'txt2' ], function(index, value) { 
  animetxt(value);  
});
```

(note that you can either type the Ids or use any selector)

```
function animetxt(id){
$o=$("#" + id);
$o.html($o.text().replace(/([\S])/g,'<span>$1</span>'));
$o.css('display','inline-block');
$('span',$o).stop().css({position:'relative',
                         display:'inline-block',
                         opacity:0,
                         fontSize:84,
                         top:function(i){return Math.floor(Math.random()*500)*((i%2)?1:-1);},
                         left:function(i){return Math.floor(Math.random()*500)*((i%2)?1:-1);}
                        }).animate({opacity:1,fontSize:20,top:0,left:0},1000);}
```

**Note**: You could also use a for loop and concat the index to the id

**Edit: Call the functions sequentially**

As  @FAngel pointed out the code above executes all at once. For a sequential execution use the function below.

This new function uses the `complete` callback of `animation` and calls itself. It stops when the next id can't be found.

You start it off like this:

```
 $(function() {
      animetxt(1);
    });
```

Here is the function:

```
function animetxt(id) {
    $o = $('#txt' + id);
    if (!$o.length) return;

    $o.html($o.text().replace(/([\S])/g, '<span>$1</span>'));
    $o.css('display', 'inline-block');
    $('span', $o).stop().css({
        position: 'relative',
        display: 'inline-block',
        opacity: 0,
        fontSize: 84,
        top: function(i) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) * ((i % 2) ? 1 : -1);
        },
        left: function(i) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) * ((i % 2) ? 1 : -1);
        }
    }).animate({
        opacity: 1,
        fontSize: 20,
        top: 0,
        left: 0
    }, {
        complete: function() {
            id++;
            animetxt(id);
        }
    }, 1000);
}​
```

Try it:

http://jsfiddle.net/ureyes84/ndScp/

Comment: In this case animation will be played for all elements simultaneously, not one after another.

Comment: how can I adapt this to get it to play one after each other?

Comment: @Aaron you could take advantage of the animate callback function or a quick hack could be adding a delay of 1000 after you call `animetxt`

Comment: @Aaron, I've modified my answer in order to animate objects one after the other.

Comment: it only animates the txt1 id now

Comment: @Aaron, I was typing off of my head. I corrected the function adn tested it. See updated answer (the problem was complete was not specified correctly(

Comment: one last thing, the timing is very wrong and even when I change it drastically it doesn't make much difference. It is very fast, Any ideas? thanks :)

Comment: still very fast, and it looks like txt2-4 appear at once... very odd.

Answer (score 0):

A more effective method would be to get your elements by classname, instead of looping through numbers to get ID's...

**HTML:**

```html
<span id="txt1" class="txt-el"></span>
<span id="txt2" class="txt-el"></span>
<span id="txt3" class="txt-el"></span>
```

**Javascript**

```js
function animetxt() {
    $('span.txt-el').each(function(index, element) {
        /*
            index: the index of the current item in the results given by $('span.txt-el')
            element: the DOM element
        */

        $o = $(element); // you can use $(this) too

        // magic stuff here
    });
}
```

Comment: what is the index and element within the function parameters?

Comment: I guess they are jQuery's arguments values (provided by the foreach). I guess I dont need to add that index & element refer to an element & in the $each

Comment: @Aaron because I'm using a class name to get the elements, you (can) have multiple elements so you get an array. The anonymous function is ran for every element in that array. `index` corresponds to the index of the array, `element` corresponds to it's value. However, `this` corresponds to the element as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
function animetxt($el){    
    if(!$el)
        $o=$("#txt1");
    else {
        $o = $el.next();
        if($o.length == 0)
           return; //stop if no more items
    }
    $o.html($o.text().replace(/([\S])/g,'<span>$1</span>'));
    $o.css('display','inline-block');
    $('span',$o).stop().css({position:'relative',
                            display:'inline-block',
                            opacity:0,
                            fontSize:84,
                            top:function(i){return Math.floor(Math.random()*500)*((i%2)?1:-1);},
                            left:function(i){return Math.floor(Math.random()*500)*((i%2)?1:-1);}
                            }).animate({opacity:1,fontSize:20,top:0,left:0},1000, function(el) { animetxt($(this)); });
```

You can do something like above. `function(el) { animetxt($(this)); }` is a complete handler of [`jQuery.animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). It is called when animation is done. Than you just need to find next element which should be animated. In my example I'm using `.next()` assuming that `txt1`, `txt2`, `txt3` etc. are siblings. And stop animation if all elements animated. You may need to find some other way to get a next element - that depends on structure of your HTML.

Comment: I get this on javascript console: Uncaught TypeError: Object txt1 has no method 'next'

Comment: How your code looks like? Do you pass an element like this: `function(el) { animetxt($(this)); }`? Important here is that `this` is wrapped with jQuery object: `$(this)`. Need to see your code to tell what is wrong there. But if you are working with jQuery object, next should work. Error tells that you are trying to call .next() of not jQuery object